Cypress - How to only click button if it contains "chevron_right"
This button has 2 states, "chevron_right" when disabled. And "expand_more" when enabled.
Its default state is "chevron_right"
The following code will click on the button the first time. But once it is enabled will error saying because it cannot find "chevron_right". Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?
cy.get('#TreeView mat-nested-tree-node').find('button').first().then(button => {
    if (cy.wrap(button).contains('chevron_right')) {
        cy.wrap(button).click()
                
    } else{
        cy.log("Do nothing")
    }
})

There are multiple buttons on the page that will have these 2 states, so i am unable to just search for 1 instance of it.

Don't cy.wrap(button) use jQuery instead.
The text() method from jQuery gets the innerText and .includes() is the javascript method to check for "contains".
cy.get('#TreeView mat-nested-tree-node').find('button').first()
  .then($button => {
    if ($button.text().includes('chevron_right')) {
        cy.wrap($button).click()
                
    } else{
        cy.log("Do nothing")
    }
})

The $ prefix on yielded parameter button is convention, but it's not needed to make this work.

Works like a charm! thanks very much
